# Get text element inside JList to a variable?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Despite a lot of research I can't find an answer or solve how to get the selected text element inside a JList to a variable. Therefore I would preciate some help. I have tried to select the index of the selected element and removed elements with this code and that works fine, but as I wrote I want the selected text to a variable after pressing a button. Thanks!

```
int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
model.removeElementAt(index);
```

Parts of my JList code:

```
model = new DefaultListModel();
list = new JList(model);
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(430, 60));
```

Parts of my actionlistener code:

```
// Select customer
if(event.getSource() == buttonSelectCustomer){
int index = list.getSelectedIndex(); // Just for test
model.removeElementAt(index); // Just for test
int number = model.getSize(); // Just for test
//String selectedText = list.getSelectedValue(); // Not working!
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`ListModel#getElementAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html#getElementAt%28int%29) method with the currently selected index. If you are certain your model only contains `String` instances, you can directly cast it to a `String` as well

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I type this: String selectedText = model.getElementAt(index); but I get an error inside Eclipse saying that I cannot convert from object to String!?

Comment: You should cast it ... isn't this a good point to grab some tutorials and start reading. For your problem, use: `String selectedText = (String)model.getElementAt(index);`, which you could probably achieve by letting Eclipse fix this for you

Comment: I agree with Robin. Read some beginners tutorial to Java and probably to swing to.

Comment: Thanks Robin. I have been reading both in book and tutorials, but this  part of creating a GUI is new for me and not in my book. Perhaps the problem is that this hand in task is a little bit above the level of that course I study in Java. Please have some patience when new beginners like me ask questions in the future

Comment: About casting, since the text in the list was of type String, then I'm just confused why they have to be cast to String again, or isn't thats what is done?

Comment: Since that method returns an `Object` and not a `String`, you must explicitly cast it. Read the casting part of this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for all details

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the selected text because you try to get it after you have removed the selected element.
you can change your code:

```
if(event.getSource() == buttonSelectCustomer)
{
    int index = list.getSelectedIndex(); // Just for test
    model.removeElementAt(index); // Just for test
    int number = model.getSize(); // Just for test
    String selectedText = list.getSelectedValue(); // Not working!
}
```

to my code:

```
if(event.getSource() == buttonSelectCustomer)
{
    String selectedText = (String)list.getSelectedValue(); // it works
    int index = list.getSelectedIndex(); // Just for test
    model.removeElementAt(index); // Just for test
    int number = model.getSize(); // Just for test
}
```

then it works.

Comment: Yes I discovered that, but the main problem was how to get the text into a String variable and I got errors in Eclipse before I run the program then I discovred that it removed the element. I forgot to remove that part of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

It's easy to retrieve the item of selected index.
Here is a simple code-snippet:

```
String[] string = new String[]{"Hello","Hi","Bye"};
JList list = new JList(string);
```

Now use the following code to get the selected item as a string:

```
String item = list.getSelectedIndex().toString();
```